# Ошибка при просмотре элемента массива в php

Tags: php, массивы

Недавно начал учить php и уже столкнулся с глупыми ошибками. Не знаю в чем причина. В общем я хочу создать массив st, состоящий из 10 одинаковых массивов, и на каждой итерации цикла выводить элемент массива st

```
for ($i=0; $i<10 ; $i++) {
  $st[$i] = array('a1','a2','a3');
  echo "$st[$i]\n";
}
```

Т.е. я ожидаю примерно следующий результат:

```
'a1','a2','a3'
'a1','a2','a3'
...
'a1','a2','a3'
```

Но в итоге получаю следующую ошибку:

> ArrayPHP Notice:  Array to string conversion

**p.s.** Нагуглил, что есть более простой способ создания массива, а именно ***array_fill***, но вопрос остается открытый. Хотелось бы разобраться в свой ошибке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `php` `echo` работает со строками. Вы же пытаетесь вывести массив, из-за чего и появляется подобная ошибка. 
Чтобы вывести все данные в подобном виде, либо переберите этот массив, примерно так:

```php
for ($i=0; $i<10 ; $i++) {
    $st[$i] = array('a1','a2','a3');
    foreach ($st[$i] as $kk){
        echo $kk.' ';
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Либо используйте `print_r`

```php
for ($i=0; $i<10 ; $i++) {
    $st[$i] = array('a1','a2','a3');
    print_r($st[$i]);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Но он выводит данные именно как массив.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь я понял, что было не так)
Но у меня появился еще вопрос. Допустим я хочу выводить не все элементы массива, а только первый (a1 10 раз). Во втором способе понятно как это сделать: 'print_r($st[$i][0]);' А как это можно сделать в первом способе?

Comment: @Edward Snowden Да не за что. Точно так же ) В этом случае, параметр уже будет строкой, и его можно вывести через `echo $st[$i][0];`